# Rails: inline CSS retrieve style from database entry

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, view, model, controller

In my HTML I have a span

> ```
> <span style="color:#??????>
>     <h3>Title</h3>
> </span>
> ```

Okay, in my database I have records which have a field that store the hash color value of a span, example `#123456` , with the hash included.

Now what I want to do is in the HTML, instead of me specifying the colour, it is retrieved directly from the database.
The model is called Sauce. The field is called title_colour.

I have tried:

> ```
> <span style="color: #{sauce.title_colour}">...</span>
> ```

The problem is that when the HTML is output, it is exactly as it is in the code. It does not extract the database value.

I think the problem is because in Rails when we display an object when already in quote marks, we start with a #, eg #{sauce.field_name} , and in CSS the color value also starts with a #. 
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the proper erb interpolation tags:

```
<span style="color: <%= sauce.title_colour %>">...</span>
```